# Add event listener to all other items on the page?

Tags: javascript

I have a search bar whose display toggles if you click onto a search icon, like so:

```
searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // toggle function that displays and hides search bar... 
});
```

For mobile, I would also like to listen for anytime a user touches outside the search bar DOM element and close it. Is there a way where an event listener can be attached to a DOM element, but listen for touches on anything other than that element?

Comment: Attach it to the whole body/document, and check the event target.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element